# Using the BoxInsetLayout class

Tags: wear-os

Looking at the docs (https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/layouts.html), I am trying to defined a layout that would be displayed correctly on a square and round device using the `BoxInsetLayout` class.

But after following the docs, that's what appears on my screen :

[image]

The box goes out of the circle, and my buttons aren't displayed correctly.

```
<android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="15dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/layout">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_volumeup"
            android:id="@+id/buttonDown"
            android:minHeight="0dp"
            android:minWidth="0dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="right|top"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button_delete"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/buttonPlay" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_volumeup"
            android:id="@+id/buttonUp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button_delete"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button_delete" />

        <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/showName"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="28dp">
    </TextView>

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:max="10"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:layout_above="@+id/buttonPlay"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/buttonPlay"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/button_play"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="54dp">
        </ImageButton>

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="X"
            android:id="@+id/button_delete"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/buttonDown" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I will answer to my own stupid question : you just have to change the padding (15dp isn't enough, I fixed it putting it to 50dp) :

```
android:padding="50dp"
```

Comment: Did it help to you? You will get the small rectangle for relativeLayout on the square device and the round device.